# import images from gallery into fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, navigation-drawer

im trying to implement a fragment inside a navigation slider. I need to create a button in 1 of my fragments to import images from my default gallery. I have tried many codes online, but they don't seem to be working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please help us help you by editing your question with answers to the following questions: What exactly have you tried? What were the results? How do these results differ from what you want?

Answer (score 0):

It depend on android version you are using if you test your app in android 6.0 than you should ask permission at runtime else image is not returned by android.

For Pre-Marshmallow you can use code:

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        pickIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 0);
```

and then override method

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, requestCode, data);
        try {
            // When an Image is picked
            if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage)));
            } else
                new ShowErrorToast(getActivity(), "Hey! your Android phone is busy");

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
```

than use method to get path of image

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri data) {
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(data
                , filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        String picturePath = "";
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
        }
        return picturePath;
    }
```

For Marshmallow you should ask for permission runtime and follow above code

Comment: thanks for the help. As I mentioned above. I need a button to be clicked but I couldn't recognize where a user is going to click for all the coding you gave above. Shouldn't be there any onClick method on something. What should I write in my xml file.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Eventually I got my answer. My mistake was that I wasn't using "view group" .Now I did. Its working perfectly.